# Call WebServcie Only once?

Tags: android, ios, json, cocoa

I am getting some data from webservice. and load that data to the tableview that contains 5 images and some string data get perfectly and load succesfully to the tableview. but when user tapped on butoon clicked once aagain call that webservcie again. and load that data in that tableview once again.

I want to prevent that load duplicate again. how may i do this.

I tried to save when user tapped on button clicked save the key in NsuserDefault. and then check weathe if key is present no call to webservice and if key is not preset dont call webservice but it shows blank in tablview. after the key has been saved in NsDictionary.

Code is here.

```
-(void)btnCliked
{
  AppDelegate * delegate=(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];


    NSLog(@"%@",[delegate.def objectForKey:@"Check"]);

    if([delegate.def objectForKey:@"Check"])
    {


    }
    else
    {
    delegate.str= [delegate.imgurl stringByAppendingString:@"getappdata.php"];    // Get data through php file

    NSLog(@"%@",delegate.str);

    NSURL * url=[NSURL URLWithString:delegate.str];

    NSData * data=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

    NSError * error;

    //Get json data in Dictionary
    NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error: &error];

    NSLog(@"%@",json);

    NSLog(@"%@",delegate.firstArray);

    NSArray * responseArr = json[@"Deviceinfo"];

    for(NSDictionary * dict in responseArr)
    {
        [delegate.firstArray addObject:[dict valueForKey:@"Appname"]];
        [delegate.secondArray addObject:[dict valueForKey:@"Description"]];
        [delegate.thirdArray addObject:[dict valueForKey:@"Icon"]];
        [delegate.fourthArray addObject:[dict valueForKey:@"Link"]];

    }

    NSLog(@"%@",delegate.firstArray);
    NSLog(@"%@",delegate.secondArray);
    NSLog(@"This is image path array %@",delegate.thirdArray);
    NSLog(@"this is  App Link Array %@",delegate.fourthArray);


    [delegate.def setObject:delegate.firstArray forKey:@"Check"];
    [delegate.def synchronize];

    }

    GetMoreAppsViewController * gmavc=[[GetMoreAppsViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"GetMoreAppsViewController" bundle:nil];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:gmavc animated:YES];
}
```

how may i solve this.

thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this way

1)Declare this variable as global

```
NSDictionary *json
```

2) Check this variable first when button clicked

```
if(json==nil)
    {
       // call web service

    }
```

Comment: how can i acess my tablview in this class tableViewController.fetchedObjects